# Mail Merge Skip if X and Y are blank

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

In my excel sheet column A is always populated by the date and then B to G are then populated by other information (not necessarily all cells are filled) which I am then mail merging into a word document. I want to skip the entry if all B to G are empty.

[image: Example table]

So in the example above I would want it to skip rows 3 and 6.

I tried doing a nested if statement like this:

{ IF { MERGEFIELD apple }<>“” “” “{ IF { MERGEFIELD Banana }<>“” “” “{ IF { MERGEFIELD Berry }<>“” “” “{ IF { MERGEFIELD Pineapple }<> “” “” “{ NEXT }” }

However, it doesn't allow me to have a NEXT field within other fields.

Is this possible? Or will I have to go into the excel sheet and put in an entry where B to G are empty? (which would be awkward because the sheet is generated by another piece of software).

Comment: This is more an end-user issue... If you go to the "Mailings" tab there's a button that let's you select which records to merge. In that dialog box there's a "link" for more advanced filtering. Here's you can choose a mergefield and set a criterium for it, such as "Is empty". Do that for each of these fields, using the "And" option in the filter. That will leave the records out of the merge entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The field coding for that would be:

```
{SKIPIF{={IF{MERGEFIELD apple}= "" 0 1}+{IF{MERGEFIELD Banana}= "" 0 1}+{IF{MERGEFIELD Berry}= "" 0 1}+{IF{MERGEFIELD Pineapple}= "" 0 1}}= 0}
```

I note that you refer to columns B-G, but your field tests concern only columns D-G; I have replicated only the latter.